# Tracking compiler flags within a Shake Action

Tags: shake-build-system

I need to track compiler flags used as part of a rule, e.g [when supplied as arguments to a function](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/shake-c-0.4.0.0/docs/src/Development.Shake.C.html#dynLibR). Does Shake have a way to track such flags as inputs in the same vein as `need`? As a trivial example, I would like for Shake to rebuild all `.o` files when the rule changes to pass `-O2` to the C compiler instead of `-O0`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches to tracking things like whether to use optimisation or not.

**1) Use Oracles**

Oracles very closely match what you are asking for. To track something like
`-O0` vs `-O2` you'd need an oracle that tracks optimisation level:

```
newtype OptLevel = OptLevel ()
    deriving (Show,Typeable,Eq,Hashable,Binary,NFData)
type instance RuleResult OptLevel = String

rules = do
    addOracle $ \(OptLevel _) -> return $
        if <whatever you use to decide> then "-O0" else "-O2"

    "foo.o" %> \_ -> do
        level <- askOracle $ OptLevel ()
        cmd "gcc" level ...
```

Now the optimisation level is a tracked dependency which will update if anything changes. This example is based on the docs for `addOracle`.

**2) Use different output files**

For compiler flags another approach is to use different build directories, i.e. so `build/opt` (and `build/opt/obj` etc) has binaries and `.o` files built with `-O`, `build/debug` without, `build/profile` with profiling flags, and `build/test` with test flags.  Some others, like `build/doc` and `build/hsc`, have generated files that aren't dependent on compiler flags.

The advantage of this approach is that you can keep all the files cached at once, and refreshing the debug or test build doesn't destroy the opt one.
The disadvantage is that it's just for a set of hardcoded
flags.  But it's also not hard to add a new mode, you just need a new
(directory, flags) pair for it.

Comment: This question is based on information from https://groups.google.com/d/msg/shake-build-system/50Xmy4AXPuc/iLANIOqXBgAJ

Answer (score 0):

You might write files that contain the options. E.g. if the output is named "hello.exe" you could provide a file "hello.options" containing the compiler options.